# Cordova MFP plugin

Tags: cordova, ionic-framework, ibm-mobilefirst, mobilefirst-adapters

I am working on a project which require IBM MobileFirst as an integral part of the application so, trying to invoke the function `Wl.send()`, to make a connection to the database but seems in the new `cordova-plugin-mfp` it has been deprecated,
please suggest me the alternate of this function or the new invoking procedure of this function.

here are my ionic info and plugin details with MobileFirst Veriosn 8.0

```
@ionic/cli-utils  : 1.10.2
ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.10.3
```

local packages:

```
@ionic/app-scripts : 2.1.4
Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.6.1
```

System:

```
Node : v6.10.3
npm  : 3.10.10
OS   : Windows 8.1
cordova-plugin-console 1.0.5 "Console"
cordova-plugin-device 1.1.6 "Device"
cordova-plugin-dialogs 1.3.3 "Notification"
cordova-plugin-globalization 1.0.7 "Globalization"
cordova-plugin-mfp 8.0.2017090705 "IBM MobileFirst Platform Foundation"
cordova-plugin-mfp-push 8.0.2017082110 "IBM MobileFirst Platform Foundation - Push Notifications"
cordova-plugin-okhttp 2.0.0 "OkHttp"
cordova-plugin-splashscreen 4.0.3 "Splashscreen"
cordova-plugin-statusbar 2.2.2 "StatusBar"
cordova-plugin-whitelist 1.3.1 "Whitelist"
ionic-plugin-keyboard 2.2.1 "Keyboard"
```

Below is the code we are using to connect to data base

```
   var resourceRequest = new WLResourceRequest("adapters/SQLAdapter/unprotected", WLResourceRequest.GET);

   console.log(resourceRequest);
   resourceRequest.send().then((response) => {
     console.log("Here I am in...");
       console.log(response.responseText);
     },(error) => { 
       console.log("error in function:-");
       console.log(error);
   });
```

Error in the code is :-

```
Error:--- ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'getItem' of undefined at __WLDAO.getItem (ibmmfpf-preview.js:8285) at getItemFromMap () –
```

Comment: you should mention which version of MobileFirst you are using.

Comment: @ionic/cli-utils  : 1.10.2
    ionic (Ionic CLI) : 3.10.3

local packages:

    @ionic/app-scripts : 2.1.4
    Ionic Framework    : ionic-angular 3.6.1

System:

    Node : v6.10.3
    npm  : 3.10.10
    OS   : Windows 8.1

Comment: edit your question and keep these thing in question itself. also mention which mobilefirst version ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try to downgrade the cordova-plugin-mfp and then try to invoke it, seems they have not released the document. I am working with cordova-plugin-mfp

8.0.2017072706

try with it

Comment: @Manish Prajapati please try with another plugin version also, if it doesnt work for you.

Comment: thank you very much as with the above version itself my code is working fine

Answer (score 0):

> new invoking procedure in MobileFirst 8.0

To invoke the procedure you have to use **WLResourceRequest** and **resourceRequest.send()**.

For example:

```
var resourceRequest = new WLResourceRequest(
    "/adapters/JavaAdapter/users",
    WLResourceRequest.GET
);
var formParams = {"param1": "value1", "param2": "value2"};
resourceRequest.sendFormParameters(formParams);

resourceRequest.send().then(
    onSuccess,
    onFailure
)
```

I suggest that you will take a tour of the MobileFirst Foundation Development in Cordova or ionic based applications . See here:

Integrating MobileFirst Foundation 8.0 in Ionic-based apps: https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/blog/2016/07/19/integrating-mobilefirst-foundation-8-in-ionic-based-apps/

Adding the MobileFirst Foundation SDK to Cordova Applications: https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/application-development/sdk/cordova/

Resource request from JavaScript (Cordova, Web) applications: https://mobilefirstplatform.ibmcloud.com/tutorials/en/foundation/8.0/application-development/resource-request/javascript/

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I know this method but it is not working, it was working just before the latest update of cordova-mfp-plugin. but since I updated my plugin We are not able to call the method

Error:---


ERROR TypeError: Cannot read property 'getItem' of undefined
    at __WLDAO.getItem (ibmmfpf-preview.js:8285)
    at getItemFromMap ()

Comment: can you post your code sample what you are using to invoke procedure ? update code in your question itself..

Comment: Are you noticing this error when running preview mode? If so, test in a simulator or actual device and check if it is working fine?

Comment: @VivinK Yah this error is while previewing the application but I tried it on device as well so same error was there during debugging through device.

Comment: @ManishPrajapati can you update your error exactly what you are getting ?

Comment: @VivinK   ERROR UPDATED

Comment: Does the flow enter the success callback? If so, print the entire contents of the response and see if you are missing something.